# WPF draggable and clickable button

Tags: c#, wpf, click, drag

I have a borderless, transparent `Window` with only one `Button`.

[My fancy button looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9h4nf.png)

The expected behaviour is:

- When I click and drag the Button, the Button must follow the cursor.
- When I only click on the Button, the MouseDown, PreviewMouseDown events or Command binding should raise.

At first I tried to call the *DragMove()* on PreviewMouseDown event, but that blocks the click events. Now my idea is: I set a 100ms delay after mouse down. If the time passed, than the button wil be dragging, otherwise it was just a click.

### Code

```
private bool _dragging;
private Point startpos;
CancellationTokenSource cancellation;

private void Button_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (_dragging && e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        var currentpos = e.GetPosition(this);
        Left += currentpos.X - startpos.X;
        Top += currentpos.Y - startpos.Y;
    }
}

private async void Button_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ChangedButton != MouseButton.Left)
        return;

    _dragging = false;
    startpos = e.GetPosition(this);

    cancellation?.Cancel();
    cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();

    await Task.Delay(100, cancellation.Token).ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        _dragging = !task.IsCanceled;
    });
}

private void Button_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (_dragging)
    {
        _dragging = false;
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    cancellation?.Cancel();
}
```

Basically it works, but has some bugs:

- When I hold down the mouse button for longer time and release, then the click won't work, because after 100ms the dragging will be active.
- After I dragged the button, and click anywhere outside the `Button` and `Window` control, the PreviewMouseDown and PreviewMouseUp events are raised. I don't know why??

Does somebody have any better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first problem:
You must handle the case when your button is pushed down but not moved. I think a better way to do this (instead of the 100ms delay) would be to specify a minimum threshold of movement above which the dragging will start.
You could do it like this:

```cs
private const double _dragThreshold = 1.0;
private bool _dragging;
private Point startpos;
CancellationTokenSource cancellation;

private void Button_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var currentpos = e.GetPosition(this);
    var delta = currentpos - startpos;
    if ((delta.Length > _dragThreshold || _dragging) && e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        _dragging = true;
        Left += currentpos.X - startpos.X;
        Top += currentpos.Y - startpos.Y;
    }
}

private async void Button_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ChangedButton != MouseButton.Left)
        return;

    _dragging = false;
    startpos = e.GetPosition(this);

    cancellation?.Cancel();
    cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
}
```

For your second problem: the button will capture the mouse on the mouse down event.
You need to release the captured mouse with the `ReleaseMouseCapture` method when you are done with your drag.

```cs
private void Button_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (_dragging)
    {
        _dragging = false;
        e.Handled = true;
        var button = sender as Button;
        button.ReleaseMouseCapture();
    }

    cancellation?.Cancel();
}
```

Comment: Thank you it works, I didn't know about MouseCaptureRelesae. You have my green check.